# Program to Play Videos (VLCJ) with Key Listeners and Building Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, vlcj

I volunteered to help a friend with a project, but I fear I may be over my head.  The basic idea is to take a combination of 3 inputs and based on the 6 available combinations, play a specific video.  I am using vlcj to load and play the video(s), with key listeners on top of that.  I was finally able to get them working and could load each of the 6 videos if I only listen/use a single input per video.  I'm getting hung up on the part where I wait for 3 inputs, and based on that combination, play a single video.  Below is what I have so far. I'm thinking build out an array of the 3 inputs and then check the contents of that array as compared to the 6 possible combinations.  The only problem is that I'm pretty sure I', not building it properly/cutting it off after 3 inputs/not properly comparing it in the code.  When I type in 1, 2, 3 on my keyboard while the program is running, nothing ever happens.

The code Might look a little sloppy since a lot of it was put together looking at various posts here and the tutorials vlcj offers.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
package javaapplication9;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;

public class JavaApplication9 {
private final JFrame frame;

int[] tools = new int[3];
int[] vid1 = {1, 2, 3};
int[] vid2 = {1, 3, 2};
int[] vid3 = {2, 1, 3};
int[] vid4 = {2, 3, 1};
int[] vid5 = {3, 1, 2};
int[] vid6 = {3, 2, 1};



private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new NativeDiscovery().discover();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JavaApplication9(args);
        }
    });
}

public JavaApplication9(String[] args) {
    frame = new JFrame("Tutorials");
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            mediaPlayerComponent.release();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Canvas videoSurface = mediaPlayerComponent.getVideoSurface();
    mediaPlayerComponent.getVideoSurface().requestFocus();
    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location0");

    videoSurface.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyChar();

            for (int i = 0; i < tools.length; i++){
                tools[i] = key;
            }


           /*
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_1){
                mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location1");
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_2){
                mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location2");
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_3){
                mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location3");
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_4){
                mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location4");
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_5){
                mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location5");
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_6){
                mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location6");
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
                frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            }

             */


        }
    });

    if (tools == vid1){
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location1");
    }

}
```

}

All of the stuff in the comment section is how I got it working with a single input per video (using e.getKeyCode() instead of e.getKeyChar())

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

@MadProgrammer - what your update included is essentially what I wound up doing using the list1.equals(list2) command, though I assume your method is a much more foolproof way to go about this.

I am still running into the issue of the array being built with inputs (will only be using 1,2,3 in the final product) does not update a key's position in the array if that key already exists in the array.  For example, I press keys 1,2,3 and build array/list `[key1, key2, key3]`, which would play `vid1`.  If I want to immediately play `vid3` after, and try to punch in 2,1,3, a new array does not build because all those inputs are already part of the output array, despite being a different order.  However, going to 4,5,6 then back to 2,1,3 will work.

Is there a way to completely clear the array when a 4th key is pressed, and have that 4th key be in position 0 of the 2nd array being built, leading to a new output array - a rearranged version of the first?

Comment: `KeyListener` is fickle, in order to generate key events it must not only be focusable, but must also have key board focus.  First, you will need to make `mediaPlayerComponent` or `videoSurface` focusable (`setFocsuable`) and use [`requestFocusInWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow()) to give focus to the component.  This might not work, as other things might take focus away from your component, so a `MouseListener` might be useful

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Serious question - Isn't that what 

 Canvas videoSurface = mediaPlayerComponent.getVideoSurface();
    mediaPlayerComponent.getVideoSurface().requestFocus();

 is for though?  I think I had this working properly since I was able to get 1 input to 1 output working properly...just having issues with 3 inputs to 1 output.

Comment: It depends on so many factors.  As `requestFocus` is platform-dependent,  it's behavior can be unpredictable.  The `Canvas` might also not be focusable, so requesting focus on might not work

Comment: There's a trick that might allow you to use the key bindings api instead, but I need to test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyListener` is fickle, in order to generate key events it must not only be focusable, but must also have key board focus.

First, you will need to make `mediaPlayerComponent` or `videoSurface` focusable (`setFocsuable`) and use `requestFocusInWindow` to give focus to the component.

This might not work, as other things might take focus away from your component, so a `MouseListener` might be useful, so you can call `requestFocusInWindow` when the video surface is clicked.

A better solution would be to use the key bindings API which has been designed to help solve this problem.  The problem is, it's only designed to work with lightweight (Swing) components, not AWT components.

You could, however, use a `JPanel` as the frame's `contentPane` and add you `mediaPlayerComponent` to it.  This way you could use the `JPanel` and bind you keys to it, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;

/**
 *
 * @author swhitehead
 */
public class Player {

    private final JFrame frame;

    int[] tools = new int[3];
    int[] vid1 = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] vid2 = {1, 3, 2};
    int[] vid3 = {2, 1, 3};
    int[] vid4 = {2, 3, 1};
    int[] vid5 = {3, 1, 2};
    int[] vid6 = {3, 2, 1};

    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new NativeDiscovery().discover();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Player(args);
            }
        });
    }

    private List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>(3);

    public Player(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame("Tutorials");
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
//        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                mediaPlayerComponent.release();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        bindKey(content, KeyEvent.VK_1, "key1");
        bindKey(content, KeyEvent.VK_2, "key2");
        bindKey(content, KeyEvent.VK_3, "key3");
        bindKey(content, KeyEvent.VK_4, "key4");
        bindKey(content, KeyEvent.VK_5, "key5");
        bindKey(content, KeyEvent.VK_6, "key6");

        frame.setContentPane(content);

        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        frame.add(mediaPlayerComponent);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Canvas videoSurface = mediaPlayerComponent.getVideoSurface();
        mediaPlayerComponent.getVideoSurface().requestFocus();
//        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location0");
//
//        if (tools == vid1) {
//            mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file location1");
//        }

    }

    protected void bindKey(JComponent component, int keyCode, String name) {

        InputMap inputMap = component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = component.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false), name + ".pressed");
        actionMap.put(name + ".pressed", new PressAction(name));
    }

    protected void inputDidChange() {
        System.out.println(inputs);
    }

    public class PressAction extends InputAction {

        public PressAction(String name) {
            super(name, true);
        }

    }

    public class ReleaseAction extends InputAction {

        public ReleaseAction(String name) {
            super(name, false);
        }

    }

    public class InputAction extends AbstractAction {

        private String name;
        private boolean pressed;

        public InputAction(String name, boolean pressed) {
            this.name = name;
            this.pressed = pressed;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean didChange = false;
            if (pressed) {
                if (!inputs.contains(name)) {
                    while (inputs.size() > 2) {
                        inputs.remove(0);
                    }
                    inputs.add(name);
                    didChange = true;
                }
            } else {
                didChange = inputs.remove(name);
            }

            if (didChange) {
                inputDidChange();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

**Updated**

> If I declare vid1 as 1,2,3 and vid2 as 4,5,6 it works flawlessly to play 2 seperate videos. If I use a different order like stated above (1,3,2) right after the 1,2,3 input array, it doesn't like it and will just keep playing the first video over again with each key press. Is there a way to clear the array and start over again once a 4th input is pressed, rather than overwriting the array using the most recent key presses? This method only seems to work if the 2nd set of inputs are entirely different from the 1st.

This is because `List#contains` doesn't care about the order the elements are in...

So, given...

```
private List<String> vid1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"key1", "key2", "key3"}));
private List<String> vid2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"key4", "key5", "key6"}));
private List<String> vid3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"key1", "key3", "key2"}));
```

I used...

```
protected void inputDidChange() {
    System.out.println(inputs);

    if (contains(vid1, inputs)) {
        System.out.println("vid1");
    } else if (contains(vid2, inputs)) {
        System.out.println("vid2");
    } else if (contains(vid3, inputs)) {
        System.out.println("vid3");
    }
}

protected boolean contains(List<String> source, List<String> compare) {
    boolean contains = source.size() == compare.size();
    if (contains) {
        for (int index = 0; index < source.size(); index++) {
            if (!source.get(index).equals(compare.get(index))) {
                contains = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return contains;
}
```

which checks each element at each index to see if they are equal

> Is there a way to completely clear the array when a 4th key is pressed, and have that 4th key be in position 0 of the 2nd array being built, leading to a new output array - a rearranged version of the first?

You could change the `actionPerformed` method of the `InputAction` to something more like...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    boolean didChange = false;
    if (pressed) {
        if (!inputs.contains(name)) {
            if (inputs.size() >= 3) {
                inputs.clear();
            }
            inputs.add(name);
            didChange = true;
        }
    } else {
        didChange = inputs.remove(name);
    }

    if (didChange) {
        inputDidChange();
    }
}
```

Basically, if the size of the `inputs` is `>= 3` when a key is pressed, the `List` is cleared and the new key is added

Remember, just because I use `String`s for the "commands", doesn't mean you have to, you can use `int` or any other object you want

Comment: So I'm seeing the inputs being recorded in the output window as `[key1, key2, key3] `, but these are still not able to play the video file when comparing the vid1 array to this newly built array based on inputs (I changed formatting of the vid1 array so that they can be compared in the if statement properly). 

Also I'm noticing that I can't rearrange the inputs 1, 2, 3 until inputs 4,5,6 are pressed, which will not be used in the final project.

Comment: The example simple builds a List of the last three keys pressed (ordered from oldest to newest), you can control the naming using the bindKey method and/or change your arrays. You will need to devise a means to compare the contents of the list with each of your arrays (removeAll comes to mind) and take appropriate actions

Comment: Oh `List#containsAll` might be better then using `removeAll`

Comment: I believe I am properly comparing the lists (vid1 and inputs), but still the video doesn't load into the frame.  Am I declaring the if statement in the wrong location or at the wrong time?

`List<String> vid1 = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2", "key3");`
`private List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>(3);`
`bindKey(content, KeyEvent.VK_1, "key1");
        bindKey(content, KeyEvent.VK_2, "key2");
        bindKey(content, KeyEvent.VK_3, "key3");`
`if (inputs.containsAll(vid1)) {
            mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("media file");
        }`

I also tried using if inputs == vid1

Comment: So I was declaring it in the wrong location..which I assumed.  I knew I needed it as an override, but it just occurred to me to put it in the Override with the array-building code.  The `List#containsAll` isn't quite what I want, as the order of the "keys" in the array is important here so I'll use `inputs.equals(vid1)`.  Now when I use this it doesn't seem like the array rewrites itself when using the same 3 inputs - ie 123 vs 132 play the same video despite declaring vid1 and vid2 to correspond with above and play different videos if true.

Comment: If I declare vid1 as 1,2,3 and vid2 as 4,5,6 it works flawlessly to play 2 seperate videos.  If I use a different order like stated above (1,3,2) right after the 1,2,3 input array, it doesn't like it and will just keep playing the first video over again with each key press.  Is there a way to clear the array and start over again once a 4th input is pressed, rather than overwriting the array using the most recent key presses?  This method only seems to work if the 2nd set of inputs are entirely different from the 1st.

Comment: Updated my original post.  Would move this to chat if I had more rep : /

Comment: That is what I'm looking for, but it is still not clearing the original array if the 4th key pressed is any one of the three already present in the array, which is frustrating.  I can make an array `[1,2,3]` and then hit "4", making a new array `[4]` (then can hit two of 1-3 again to make say `[4,1,2]`) but I can't hit 3 after having `[1,2,3]` to start a new array with 3 as the first element.  I only want to use a total of 3 inputs, so this behavior won't work. Any reason why it would act in this manner?

Comment: `if (!inputs.contains(name)) {` is preventing duplicates, this is deliberate because if the user holds the key down, the `actionPerformed` event will be called repeatedly.  You could update it to something like `if (!inputs.contains(name) || inputs.size() >= 3) {`

Comment: Thank you!!! That line of code didn't quite give me the result I was looking for, but based on all your input and help, I was able to better understand the code and commands you provided, and manipulated them in a way that made my program work flawlessly!  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Yep, sorry, wasn't really testing the last few :P